# When the sql query are executed by ORM with rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, orm

if I make a function :

```
def test
    User.where(name: 'foo')
    return 42
end
```

If I call `test` method the sql is not done.

So `where` method just construct the request but not execute it.
It's like that we can add `where` or others sql method like `limit`, `order`...etc
Apparently, each time, this method construct request sql but not execute it.

So where, in source code, SQL are execute? What trigger this?

I don't understand the current mechanism...